# select string after second to the last occurrence of a character

Tags: sql, string, oracle

Trying to learn some Advanced Oracle Sql Formulas,
I have a field for customer,
Parent Customer : Child1 Customer : Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Customer

I need a formula that will just give me

Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Customer

The field could vary between 3 or 4 relationships, so I only want the the data after the second to the last :

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the table schema? And sample data in table format will help too.

Comment: *after the second to the last :* tranlates to *: Grandchild Customer :* for me. `instr` can search the nth occurence and also search backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'Parent Customer : Child1 Customer : Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Customer' your_field FROM dual)
SELECT your_field,
       SUBSTR(your_field, INSTR(your_field, ' : ', -1, 2) + 3) your_field_part
FROM   your_table;

YOUR_FIELD                                                                       YOUR_FIELD_PART
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------
Parent Customer : Child1 Customer : Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Custom Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Customer
```

This works by first finding the position of the start of the `:` string, starting from the last character (determined by the third parameter (`-1`) which, because it's negative, indicates we start from the first character from the end of the string instead of the beginning), then taking the string from that character + 3 (since the `:` is 3 characters in length) to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `substr()` and `instr()`. Instr gives you numbers where a substring such as `:` starts, then those numbers can be used within substr as the parameters to return just the part of the source string that you need. Instr also allows you to nominate which occurrence of that substring (as the third parameter).

```
select
      instr(customer,':',1,1) first
    , instr(customer,':',1,2) second
    , instr(customer,':',1,3) third
    , substr(customer,instr(customer,':',1,2)+2) second_and_last_part
    , substr(customer,instr(customer,':',1,2)+2, instr(customer,':',1,3)-instr(customer,':',1,2)-2) second_last_part
    , substr(customer,instr(customer,':',1,3)+2) last_part
from  (
   select 'Parent Customer : Child1 Customer : Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Customer' as customer from dual
   )
```

nb: the use of `+2` that you see above is due to the fact the the character position  of each `:` is also followed by a space, so to ignore both we add 2.

Just mix and match the various function calls with different parameters to slice the original string into parts, as in the query above:

```
+-------+--------+-------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| FIRST | SECOND | THIRD |              SECOND_AND_LAST_PART              |        LAST_PART         |   SECOND_LAST_PART   |
+-------+--------+-------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|    17 |     35 |    57 | Grandchild Customer : GreatGrandchild Customer | GreatGrandchild Customer | Grandchild Customer  |
+-------+--------+-------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [, th_appearance ] ] ) [ref](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php)

SUBSTR( string, start_position [, length ] ) [ref](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php)

Comment: That will give you the 3rd position of the character, not the 2nd last. `INSTR()` can take a negative number for the position, which means it searches backwards.

Comment: I was trying to show the "how to", so it is now expanded. I'm aware it can go backward, but don't see that as needed here.